# How to access the data of each cell in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have used a tutorial to see how to implement JTable but I don't know how exactly access the data of each cell to extract the data that the user put in these.

The table has *2* column and *N* rows

In the first column there is a *String* in the second there is a *int*

The tutorial that I have used is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: Have you tried using the `public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)` method?

Comment: What have you tried? Explain what doesn't work and post a full StackTrace if there is one. Also show some of your code (not everything, just the interesting parts!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `JTable` has a data-model connected with it. Users may add data to this data model (e.g. by calling to the `javax.swing.table.TableModel.setValueAt(Object, int, int)` method) and `JTable` then displays them. In order to process the data from the `JTable` one can use the following approach:

```
JTable t = new JTable(/* set some table-model that will contain the data */);
...
/* get some table-model that will contain the data */
TableModel tm = t.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
    Object o = tm.getValueAt(i, j);
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
      System.out.println((Integer)o);
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
      System.out.println((String)o);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to see the paragraph "[Listening for Data Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange)"

In general, you have to get the model associated with the table and call it "getValueAt" method. It returns the Object associated with the cell, so you have to cast it to String or Integer.
For example if you want to get the value of the second column and third row, the code is:

> (Integer) model.getValueAt(2,1)